# Qt Android project suddently will not start compiling

Tags: android, c++, qt

For some reason I can not compile for Android in Qt anymore. Compiling for desktop with the same compiler still works.

I get this "error":

```
20:59:17: Running steps for project Test...
20:59:17: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
20:59:17: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0.Android.win32.2nd\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0.Android.win32.2nd\5.2.0\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\trunk\Test.pro
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0.Android.win32.2nd\5.2.0\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\trunk\Test.pro
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0.Android.win32.2nd\5.2.0\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\trunk\Test.pro
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0.Android.win32.2nd\5.2.0\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\trunk\Test.pro
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0.Android.win32.2nd\5.2.0\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\trunk\Test.pro
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0.Android.win32.2nd\5.2.0\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\trunk\Test.pro
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0.Android.win32.2nd\5.2.0\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ..\trunk\Test.pro
```

and it continues forever...

I have of course tried clean, rebuild, delete whole build directory, delete and configure the .pro.user file again, but no luck. It was also difficult searching for similar posts as I get no error..

Comment: Tried creating a new project and importing the files, but still the same. I am currently reinstalling Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a reinstall of Qt it was fixed.